# Displaying text document of Chinese characters in JSP

Tags: eclipse, jsp, character-encoding

I'm using Eclipse to create a small web project. I have an article of Chinese text I want to display in my jsp page.  The article is saved in UTF-8 and I have set the character encoding to utf-8.  Chinese characters I type into the jsp file show up fine but when I try to read in and display the article text the Chinese characters aren't showing properly.  This is my code for reading the document and displaying it in my JSP page.

```
<p>你好，你今天怎么样呢？</p>
<p>我今天很好。你呢</p>

<%
     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testArticle.txt"));
     String line = "";
     while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
         out.println(line + "<BR>");
     }
     out.flush();
     input.close();
%>
```

The Chinese in the paragraph tags displays fine but the rest of it gets all messed up.  I'm not sure what is going wrong.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BufferedReader` may not read the data in correct character set.
Try this:

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("testArticle.txt"), "UTF-8");  
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(input);
```

And have you set your eclipse encoding set to UTF-8? Please set your JSP pageEncoding to UTF-8 too.